# Does the parameter specified in mapred-site.xml overrides the parameter given in code in hadoop ?

Tags: java, hadoop

If i have specified the value of parameter mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum in mapred-site.xml to be 2 and if the code of the program specified the reduce task to be as 
job.setNumReduceTasks(1), then will the parameter specified in mapred-site.xml be ignored or will it obeyed and the 2 reduce tasks will be executed simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixed up by `mapred.reduce.tasks` and `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum`. Actually, `job.setNumReduceTasks(1)` will set `mapred.reduce.tasks` to 1. And `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` is the maximum number of reduce tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker. These are two totally different parameters.

What's more, the value of `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` in `mapred-site.xml` is the only effective value. You can not change it as the task tracker uses it when it is starting. `mapred.reduce.tasks` is a property for one Job. Different Jobs can have differerent `mapred.reduce.tasks` values.

Comment: Great piece of explanation.